# How to use a String from an Array for cell text in tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm trying to use the string in the "0" position of  excersizeArray for the cell text in a table view. How do I change my current code to make that work? ExcersizeArray is nested in an array called plistArray.

This is what I'm using:

```
cell.text = [excersizeArray objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)index];
```

With the current code, I am not getting any text in the tableview table.

Comment: two questions for you: a)  What is your question? b) How is index defined?

Comment: Also - the current way to set text is `cell.textLabel.text = …`

Comment: Thanks! I'm brand new to Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see an actual question in your "question", but....

If your doing this in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, try:

```
cell.text = [excersizeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Will that give me the array object or a string inside the array object?

Comment: Also - the current way to set text is cell.textLabel.text = … – Abizern :P

Comment: novicePrgrmr - it depends on how your array is set up.  @Miraaj - usually true, he could have a custom cell class, but your probably correct in this case.

Comment: @novicePrgrmr - The above will give you the object at that index.  So if you have an array of strings, this will give a string.  If its an array of arrays, it will give you an array.